# An easy question about contractive completely positive map

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Recall that a map $\phi: M\rightarrow N$ of von Neumann algetras is **normal** if 
$$\phi(sup x_{i})=sup\phi(x_{i})$$
 for all norm bounded, monotone increasing nets of self-adjoint elements $\{x_{i}\}\subset M$.

Let $N$ be a von Neumann algebras and $M_{n}{(\mathbb{C})}$ be a compelx matrix, if 
$$\phi: M_{n}{(\mathbb{C})} \rightarrow N$$
 is a contractive completely positive map, then $\phi $ is a normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Because $M_n(\mathbb C)$ is a finite-dimensional von Neumann algebra, so if $x_i\nearrow x$ for $x_i$ selfadjoint for all $i$, then $x_i\to x$ in norm. So 
$$
\phi(x)=\phi(\lim x_i)=\lim \phi(x_i)\ \ \ \text{ (in norm)}.
$$
As $\phi$ preserves positivity, we have $\phi(x_i)\leq\phi(x)$, and with the limit being in norm, it is also a strong limit; so $\phi(x_i)\nearrow\phi(x)$.

Comment: Maybe, in $M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ the norm topology and the ultraweak topology are equivalent, so a c.c.p map is also continuous in ultraweak topology. Hence, it is normal.